# Как использовать Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS для шаблонного класса (template class)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++11, макрос

Например, имеем темплейтный класс и в нем определяем тип флагов (QFlag):

```
template <class ValueType>
class Object
{
public:
...
    enum CompleteOption {
        NotComplete = 0x0,
        ForcibleComplete = 0x1,
        ValueComplete = 0x2,
        LinkListComplete = 0x4
    };
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(CompleteOptions, CompleteOption)
...
};
```

Ясно, что "просто так" макрос `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` для него не заработает (только если напрямую указать параметр шаблона, например:

```
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(QFlags<Object<char>::CompleteOption>)
```

), но тогда надо будет декларировать для каждого типа. Плохо.

Попытался определить операторы вручную:

```
template <class ValueType>
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QIncompatibleFlag operator|(Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type f1, int f2)
{ return QIncompatibleFlag(int(f1) | f2); }

template <class ValueType>
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags<Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type> operator|(Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type f1, Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type f2)
{ return QFlags<Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type>(f1) | f2; }

template <class ValueType>
Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline QFlags<Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type> operator|(Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type f1, QFlags<Object<ValueType>::CompleteOptions::enum_type> f2)
{ return f2 | f1; }
```

Получаю (в числе прочих) ошибку:

> declaration of 'operator|' as non-function

Непонятно, что хочет?
Может кто предложит готовое/удобное решение, чтобы мозг слишком не ломать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
struct CompleteOptionClass{
    enum CompleteOption {
        NotComplete = 0x0,
        ForcibleComplete = 0x1,
        ValueComplete = 0x2,
        LinkListComplete = 0x4
    };
    Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(CompleteOptions, CompleteOption)
};
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(CompleteOptionClass::CompleteOptions)

template<class T>
class Object : public CompleteOptionClass{
//...
};
```

Comment: Просто, эффективно, остноумно 

(Кажется у вас в примере в скобках у `Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS` должно стоять `CompleteOptionClass::CompleteOptions` (s на конце))